# C# Printable PDF .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdf-generation

I'm developing a .NET Core 2.0 console app to convert PDF into PDF printable (images).

That is same thing as do: Windows 10 - Microsoft Print to PDF, the result is a new PDF with same aspect but made of images.

But I need to do this programatically. Is there any way I could do similar conversion that Microsoft Print to PDF does in C#?

Comment: Replace what you are using now, iText 5, with iText 7 + pdfHTML.

Comment: *"But if I print the file..."* - which file? A html you get from pdf2htmlEX? A pdf you create using your iTextSharp 4.6.1?

Comment: Te original PDF file, I cant convert it to HTML because pdf2htmlEX give me errors, but if I print it with Microsoft Print to PDF it converts OK.